# Proving $f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 + z}$ is continuous in the right-half plane.

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove $f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 + z}$ is continuous in the right-half plane $\{z \in \mathbb{C}: Re(z) > 0\}$.

I need some help with this one. First, write $z = a + ib$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. Then I noticed that for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\big| \frac{1}{n^2 + z} \big| = \big| \frac{1}{n^2 + a + ib} \big| = \frac{1}{|n^2 + a + ib|} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(n^2 + a)^2 + b^2}} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^4}} = \frac{1}{n^2}$ since $a = Re(z) > 0$. By Weierstrass M-Test, $f(z)$ is an absolutely and uniformly convergent series.

What can I do from here? Thanks.

Comment: That's it. The partial sums are continuous and converge uniformly so the limit function is continuous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you know that the series is uniformly convergent on the right half-plane, simply observe that $f$ is the uniform limit of

$$f_N := \sum_{n = 1}^N \frac{1}{n^2 + z}.$$

Now each $f_N$ is a finite sum of continuous functions on the right half-plane.